Split Time period with one row for each month
i have data from an observational study with a start and an end to the follow up for every patient. I would like to split this period by months, with one row equal to
The data frame looks like this :
df <- data.frame(
  PATIENT = c(1,2, 3, 4),
  Start = c("2016-01-01", "2017-12-01", "2016-03-01", "2016-02-01"),
  End = c("2016-05-30","2018-01-30","2016-06-30","2016-05-30")
)

The expected output would look like this :
 data.frame(
  PATIENT = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4),
  PERIOD = c("2016-01-01", "2016-02-01", "2016-03-01", "2016-04-01", "2016-05-01",
              "2017-12-01","2018-01-01",
              "2016-03-01","2016-04-01","2016-05-01","2016-06-01",
              "2016-02-01","2016-03-01","2016-04-01","2016-05-01")
)

(If someone's curious, or if it helps the search of someone in the same struggle, i'm looking into this to use TrialEmulation, a new package useful to emulate trial for observational data)
I've used tmerge but i struggled to make this work with the desired outcome, i've also had a look at TimeSplitter but with no success

Your expected output data frame is not working, but assuming you want 5 entries for patient 1.

Sorry, my mistake

An approach using seq.Date.
First making sure the dates are really class(Date)
df$Start <- as.Date(df$Start)

df$End <- as.Date(df$End)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(PERIOD = list(seq.Date(Start, End, "month")), 
         Start = NULL, End = NULL, .by = PATIENT) %>% 
  unnest(PERIOD)
# A tibble: 15 × 2
   PATIENT PERIOD    
     <dbl> <date>    
 1       1 2016-01-01
 2       1 2016-02-01
 3       1 2016-03-01
 4       1 2016-04-01
 5       1 2016-05-01
 6       2 2017-12-01
 7       2 2018-01-01
 8       3 2016-03-01
 9       3 2016-04-01
10       3 2016-05-01
11       3 2016-06-01
12       4 2016-02-01
13       4 2016-03-01
14       4 2016-04-01
15       4 2016-05-01

If you want base R
do.call(rbind, 
  apply(df, 1, \(x) 
    data.frame(
      PATIENT = x["PATIENT"], 
      PERIOD = seq.Date(as.Date(x["Start"]), 
                        as.Date(x["End"]), "month"), row.names=NULL)))
   PATIENT     PERIOD
1        1 2016-01-01
2        1 2016-02-01
3        1 2016-03-01
4        1 2016-04-01
5        1 2016-05-01
6        2 2017-12-01
7        2 2018-01-01
8        3 2016-03-01
9        3 2016-04-01
10       3 2016-05-01
11       3 2016-06-01
12       4 2016-02-01
13       4 2016-03-01
14       4 2016-04-01
15       4 2016-05-01

